# How to find a pattern between the special characters { and \?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I've been learning how to work with z/VM through the zLinux console. I've sent a CMS command to a z/VM guest and had the output return to a file on zLinux. Now all that is left is to cleanup the file and extract the right date through a pattern.

I noticed that the file contains the right data between a { and a \. The pattern opens with a { and ends with a . See the example below.

**Example:**

```
 &{HELLO WORLD TEST 123 \INMR06
```

There are many lines like these and I tried extracting the pattern using the commands:

1. `awk -F"[{\]" '{print $2}' TMPCMS`

   **Result:** *HELLO WORLD TEST 123 \INMR06*
2. `awk -F"[{\\]" '{print $2}' TMPCMS`

   Result: awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain` ]'

   ```
              *HELLO WORLD TEST 123 \INMR06*
   ```

I would like to get only the string "HELLO WORLD TEST 123" between the { and \, and ignore "\INRM06".

I just don't seem to be able to escape that "\".

Yours truly,

Joeyb276

---

Comment: Part of your problem is you're using the wrong type of quotes in `-F"[{\\]"`. Always use single quotes (`'`) by default and double quotes (`"`) only when you **need** to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes - it's extremely important to understand the difference between the 2 types of quoting and not quoting if you're going to be doing any shell programming.

Comment: In awk the reason you need ```\\\\``` instead of ```\\``` to escape a backslash is that you're specifying a **string** to be used as the FS (which is just a type of regular expression with some extra bells and whistles) so before it can be used as a regexp awk has to convert the **string** into a **regexp**. That conversion requires one parse of the string which uses up a set of escapes. So during the conversion of string to regexp the string ```\\\\``` is converted to the regexp ```\\``` and THERE is the single escape you'd use if writing a regexp literal `/\\/` in a different context.

Comment: If you used `"` instead of `'` around the string then you'd be asking the shell to ALSO parse the string before awk even sees it thus introducing yet a third round of parsing before it becomes a regexp in awk so you'd need to write ```"\\\\\\\\"``` to end up with ```\\``` in the regexp! So - know your quotes!

Comment: if you have grep with PCRE option, you can also use `grep -oP '{\K.*?(?=\\)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***OP's code fix:*** Good try and you were close. If you do the escaping properly of `\` character inside your field separator you could get it done. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'{| \\\\' '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

***Bonus solution:*** You could use `match` function of `awk` to match between `{` to `\`:

```
awk 'match($0,/{[^\\]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the escape of the back-slash. :D

```
awk -F'[{\\\\]' '{print $2}'
```

For this specific problem you can just use two `sub()`, it may be easier to read:

```
awk  'sub(/[^{]*{/,"")+sub(/\\.*/,"")'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sed` with the following command:

```
sed -n 's/^[^{]*{\(.*\)\\[^\\]*$/\1/p' TMPCMS
```

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/6mmEn2).

The `-n` option suppresses default line output, the pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[^{]*` - zero or more chars other than `{`
- `{` - a `{` char
- `\(.*\)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[^\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`
- `$` - end of string

The `\1` replacement only keeps the value of Group 1 and `p` option prints it.